# Angular cli Generates Wrong Directory Path in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using:

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.4
node: 8.2.1
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.1
@angular/common: 4.3.1
@angular/compiler: 4.3.1
@angular/core: 4.3.1
@angular/forms: 4.3.1
@angular/http: 4.3.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.1
@angular/router: 4.3.1
@angular/cli: 1.2.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.1
@angular/language-service: 4.3.1
```

I've been using the Angular cli for a while now and today I started a new project on the same machine, same everything. I started the project as usual with `ng new mytest`. I ran `ng serve` and everything was fine.

Then I generated a new component in `mytest/src/app/` like I always do. This was a navbar component. I ran `ng g c navbar`. When the Angular cli updated my `app.module.ts` it wrote:

```
import { NavbarComponent } from '.src/app/navbar/navbar.component';
```

This is actually wrong because the component is inside of `app/`. When I ran `ng serve` again it threw an error:

```
ERROR in /home/ubuntu/angular/mytest/src/app/app.module.ts (5,33): Cannot find module '.src/app/navbar/navbar.component'.
```

I had to change the import statement to:

```
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component'
```

I don't see how this is possible. I've never had this happen.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug.
It is under `need: investigation` label.

The solution until a fix is going to be implemented is to use @angular/cli: older version.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed in @angular/cli [1.3.2](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.3.2) now.